# Reading A Fixed Format Text File

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, oledb

Its been years since I have had to attempt to read a file using either Microsoft Text ODBC Driver or Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0 Provider.

So I have the following code

```
public void Example()
{
string CVS = Application.StartupPath;
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM [MyFile.txt]";
string Connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+CVS+";"+"Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed;";
OleDbDataAdapter OLE = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL,Connection);
DataTable Table = new DataTable();
OLE.Fill(Table);
}
```

When I run the above code I get an "Unexpected Error", I know I am missing something, I am not sure what exactly.

Sources:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile
http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db
http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Importing_CSV_Database_Schema.ini.aspx

Any direction would be appreciated.

Let us assume the Schema.ini file is correct.

Comment: Whoa, didn't know we could read text files like that.

Comment: Try adding a trailing backslash to the path in the connection string.  It was explicitly added in the third source's example.  It might make a difference.

Comment: If you're dealing with a delimited file, would it be easier to read it line by line?

Answer (score 5):

Remove ' (just prior to 'text;) from the connection string.

In order to resolve the "Could not find installable ISAM", run the following command:
Regsvr32 c:\winnt\system32\mstext40.dll
* Make sure that file is in that folder first. And change WINNT to whatever your windows directory is.

Comment: Change winnt to your windows directory.

Comment: You could use Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in the connection string.  You can also support both Ace and Jet, if you wished.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255.  To use this download:
1.If you are the user of an application, consult your application documentation for details on how to use the appropriate driver.
2.If you are an application developer using OLEDB, set the Provider argument of the ConnectionString property to “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0”

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not a real answer to your question, but i would really rethink about using this architecture to read in a file.

I would really prefer something like [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), cause it gives you much more power about how the data will be interpreted. Alternative you could also take a look into the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).